# Increase root partition

Tags: linux, hard-drive, lvm, partition

Does anyone know of a way I can extend the size of /dev/sda4 and assign it to vg_root-lv_var without a reboot?

`lsblk` output:

```
NAME                         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0                            2:0    1    4K  0 disk
sda                            8:0    0   50G  0 disk
├─sda1                         8:1    0  500M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                         8:2    0    4G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda3                         8:3    0 35.5G  0 part
│ ├─vg_root-lv_root          253:0    0    9G  0 lvm  /
│ ├─vg_root-lv_usr           253:1    0    4G  0 lvm  /usr
│ ├─vg_root-lv_localservices 253:2    0 15.5G  0 lvm  /localservices
│ ├─vg_root-lv_home          253:3    0    4G  0 lvm  /home
│ ├─vg_root-lv_tmp           253:4    0    4G  0 lvm  /tmp
│ └─vg_root-lv_var           253:5    0    4G  0 lvm  /var
└─sda4                         8:4    0    5G  0 part
  └─vg_root-lv_root          253:0    0    9G  0 lvm  /
sr0                           11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

`pvscan` output:

```
  PV /dev/sda3   VG vg_root         lvm2 [35.51 GiB / 0    free]
  PV /dev/sda4   VG vg_root         lvm2 [5.00 GiB / 0    free]
  Total: 2 [40.50 GiB] / in use: 2 [40.50 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me on EL7.

First you must have a method of growing the `/dev/sda` block device dynamically, such as increasing the size of the disk in VMware or AWS, etc. `dmesg` will report the increased size of the block device when you do this. You might need to provoke a rescan of the SCSI bus with something like `echo 1 >/sys/class/scsi_device/0:0:0:0/device/rescan`.

1. Firstly, using `fdisk`, delete the original `/dev/sda4` partition and then recreate it, starting at the **exact same sector** as the original but extending to the new end of the disk which must be either greater than or equal to the original. Ensure you set the same partition type as well. You will get a warning about needing a reboot when you save and quit, however carry on.
2. Run `partx -u /dev/sda4` which should update the kernel about the partition.
3. Run `pvresize /dev/sda4` to pick up the additional space. Your volume group should now report it has free space.
4. Now run `lvresize -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/vg_root-lv_var` which resizes the `/var` logical volume to use all of the new space. Adjust this command if you only want to use some of the new space.
5. Finally, resize the filesystem with something like `xfs_growfs /var` or `resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_root-lv_var`. This will depend on the filesystem you're using, some tools want the underlying block device, some want the filesystem mountpoint.
6. You should now have more space in `/var`.

Comment: Thank you!  I was using "partx -a /dev/sda4" instead of "partx -u"